# WCF service is not communicating with silverlight4 application on Windows 8. IE 10. IIS 8.0

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

There are two modules one is silverlight application(like a client) and another one is wcf service which is self hosted service . Here both the application works like client and server communication. Those two applications are communicating properly in windows 7 and previous versions but not in win 8.

There is an error like "
An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI "localhost:8283/MyTestService". This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details."

I tried a many ways which i referred from internet but not able to create connection between them in windows 8.

I tried these ways :
1).added two files clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml to the IIS8(wwwroot) folder as referred by MSN..
2).Giver all permissions to respective folders.

what may be the possible solutions for this ?
1). any security issues might be there
2). windows 8 is enterprise edition

If any more details required let me know in comments.

I am looking forward for your respond..

Answer (score 0):

After so much of R&D , i got the solution to work silverlight and WCF service in windows 8 environment. I am answering to my question if it may helpful to anybody caught in this type of error ..

Actual Cause :

```
 No communication is creating in between CVT Service(WCF service) and CVT pages(silver light application) as client side. Whenever it compiled in windows 8 environment . Then the error caught was “ An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI ‘http://localhost:8283. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. Please see the inner exception for more details. “.
```

Resolution :

```
The actual problem is present in WCF service . Below steps to be followed to run the WCF service successfully and make it communicate properly with silver light application in windows 8 environment. In windows 7 and previous versions the settings related to WCF service work will be enabled by default but in win 8 few features might not be enabled in that case you can follow these below steps.
```

step 1 : 
    create and add two XML files to wwwroot folder. This folder is located in this path “C:\inetpub\wwwroot”.

a). clientaccesspolicy.xml :

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
        <access-policy>
        <cross-domain-access>
         <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
            <domain uri="*"/>
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
            <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
        </grant-to>
    </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
    </access-policy>
</xml>
```

b). crossdomain.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-    policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Step 2 :  If this feature is not activated , enable this feature by following the below steps.

Hit Windows+x.
Select Programs and Features(first item on list).
Select Turn Windows Features on or off on the left.
Expand .Net Framework 4.5 Advanced Services.
Expand WCF services.
Enable HTTP Activation.

Step 3 :  Adding MIME Type and new  managed handler

WCF services don’t run on IIS 8 with the default configuration, because the web server doesn’t know, how to handle incoming requests targeting .svc files. You can teach it in two steps: 
Refer below link :
https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/

Step 4 : Application should be compiled in windows 8 environment .
We need to follow these steps to run this application in windows 8 environment.